# config file on node_modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I created a generic npm package which has my business logic, but I need some google cloud storage information that is in my config files. How can I access this file, if my package is in my node_modules folder? What would be a good solution for that?

this is the structure:

```
-config
  -google_storage_config
-node_modules
  -package
    -serviceWhichNeedsThatConfig
```

Comment: This is an irregular pattern. Consider including this config inside of your service; or during initialization of the service.

Comment: The problem is that the config files are different for different applications. How can I solve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your folder structure, we will assume your path to the config will be `../../../config/google_storage_config`, since `node_modules/package/serviceWhichNeedsThatConfig` should always be in the root directory.

---

Now, to access any variables from this config file, simply include the following code in the `serviceWhichNeedsThatConfig`,

```
var config = require('../../../config/google_storage_config');
console.log(config.myVariable);
```

Comment: If I require like that, I can not have access, I get this error message: 
Error: Cannot find module '/config/google_storage_config'

Comment: You're right! Looks like `require()` uses a relative path. See my updated answer.

Comment: I have to go back 5 path but It works! There is a better way to require files like that?

Comment: Unfortunately that's a common annoyance with Node's require(). Read this great article for some possible workarounds - https://gist.github.com/branneman/8048520

Comment: If you felt my answer solved your question, please mark it as the accepted answer to help others in the future whom may have the same issue.

Comment: Thank you! I was look around about it, and found this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv to set ENV variables, are the process.env variables global?

Comment: No, process.env variables will be bound to the particular node process in which that `dotenv` package declares them.

Answer (score 0):

Hi~Have you tried `require`?

```
var config = require('../../config/google_storage_config');
```

Comment: I used this structure as an example, But this works, for that case! Thanks